# Get order payment method name or ID in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, google-tag-manager

I'm modifying a cdc_googletagmanager module in prestashop and trying to add conditional function that will depend on choosed payment method in order. 
I've tried something like this

```
  foreach ($orders as $id_order) {
$order = new Order($params['id_order']);
$order_payment = OrderPayment::getByOrderId($id_order); }
```

But order_payment returns nothing. Is there any other method getting payment module name or ID?